# InstanceBuffer not working in DX 11_0

Tags: c++, directx-11

So I have this problem I have been stuck on for a few weeks now where the instance buffer is not working in my `DX 11_0` application, the vertex buffer and index buffers are working just fin but for some reason nothing is getting passed in to the instance buffer even though the instance buffer was created with `S_OK` and throws no *error*.

Here is the definition and creation of the instance buffer

```
instanceDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    instanceDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(InstanceVertex2) * MAX_INSTANCES;
    instanceDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
    instanceDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
    instanceDesc.StructureByteStride = 0;
    instanceDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;

    instanceData.pSysMem = new InstanceVertex2[MAX_INSTANCES];
    instanceData.SysMemPitch = 0;
    instanceData.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;

    //create the instance buffer
    result = device->CreateBuffer(&instanceDesc, &instanceData, &m_instanceBuffer);
    if (FAILED(result))
    {
        return false;
    }
```

Here is the *polygon* layout

```
//vertex position, by vertex
    polygonLayout[0].AlignedByteOffset = 0;
    polygonLayout[0].Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT;
    polygonLayout[0].InputSlot = 0;
    polygonLayout[0].InputSlotClass = D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA;
    polygonLayout[0].InstanceDataStepRate = 0;
    polygonLayout[0].SemanticIndex = 0;
    polygonLayout[0].SemanticName = "POSITION";

    //uv coords, by vertex
    polygonLayout[1].AlignedByteOffset = D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT;
    polygonLayout[1].Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT;
    polygonLayout[1].InputSlot = 0;
    polygonLayout[1].InputSlotClass = D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA;
    polygonLayout[1].InstanceDataStepRate = 0;
    polygonLayout[1].SemanticIndex = 0;
    polygonLayout[1].SemanticName = "TEXCOORD";

    //texture ID, by instance
    polygonLayout[2].AlignedByteOffset = 0;
    polygonLayout[2].Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32_SINT;
    polygonLayout[2].InputSlot = 1;
    polygonLayout[2].InputSlotClass = D3D11_INPUT_PER_INSTANCE_DATA;
    polygonLayout[2].InstanceDataStepRate = 1;
    polygonLayout[2].SemanticIndex = 0;
    polygonLayout[2].SemanticName = "TEXTUREID";

    //color, by instance
    polygonLayout[3].AlignedByteOffset = D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT;
    polygonLayout[3].Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT;
    polygonLayout[3].InputSlot = 1;
    polygonLayout[3].InputSlotClass = D3D11_INPUT_PER_INSTANCE_DATA;
    polygonLayout[3].InstanceDataStepRate = 1;
    polygonLayout[3].SemanticIndex = 0;
    polygonLayout[3].SemanticName = "COLOR";

    //UVAdd , by instance
    polygonLayout[4].AlignedByteOffset = D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT;
    polygonLayout[4].Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT;
    polygonLayout[4].InputSlot = 1;
    polygonLayout[4].InputSlotClass = D3D11_INPUT_PER_INSTANCE_DATA;
    polygonLayout[4].InstanceDataStepRate = 1;
    polygonLayout[4].SemanticIndex = 0;
    polygonLayout[4].SemanticName = "UVADD";

    //UVMultiply, by instance
    polygonLayout[5].AlignedByteOffset = D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT;
    polygonLayout[5].Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT;
    polygonLayout[5].InputSlot = 1;
    polygonLayout[5].InputSlotClass = D3D11_INPUT_PER_INSTANCE_DATA;
    polygonLayout[5].InstanceDataStepRate = 1;
    polygonLayout[5].SemanticIndex = 0;
    polygonLayout[5].SemanticName = "UVMULTIPLY";

    //matrix row 1
    polygonLayout[6].AlignedByteOffset = D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT;
    polygonLayout[6].Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT;
    polygonLayout[6].InputSlot = 1;
    polygonLayout[6].InputSlotClass = D3D11_INPUT_PER_INSTANCE_DATA;
    polygonLayout[6].InstanceDataStepRate = 1;
    polygonLayout[6].SemanticIndex = 0;
    polygonLayout[6].SemanticName = "MATRIX";

    //matrix row 2
    polygonLayout[7].AlignedByteOffset = D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT;
    polygonLayout[7].Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT;
    polygonLayout[7].InputSlot = 1;
    polygonLayout[7].InputSlotClass = D3D11_INPUT_PER_INSTANCE_DATA;
    polygonLayout[7].InstanceDataStepRate = 1;
    polygonLayout[7].SemanticIndex = 1;
    polygonLayout[7].SemanticName = "MATRIX";

    //matrix row 3
    polygonLayout[8].AlignedByteOffset = D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT;
    polygonLayout[8].Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT;
    polygonLayout[8].InputSlot = 1;
    polygonLayout[8].InputSlotClass = D3D11_INPUT_PER_INSTANCE_DATA;
    polygonLayout[8].InstanceDataStepRate = 1;
    polygonLayout[8].SemanticIndex = 2;
    polygonLayout[8].SemanticName = "MATRIX";

    //matrix row 4
    polygonLayout[9].AlignedByteOffset = D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT;
    polygonLayout[9].Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT;
    polygonLayout[9].InputSlot = 1;
    polygonLayout[9].InputSlotClass = D3D11_INPUT_PER_INSTANCE_DATA;
    polygonLayout[9].InstanceDataStepRate = 1;
    polygonLayout[9].SemanticIndex = 3;
    polygonLayout[9].SemanticName = "MATRIX";

    numElements = sizeof(polygonLayout) / sizeof(polygonLayout[0]);

    //create the input layout
    result = device->CreateInputLayout(polygonLayout, numElements, vertexShaderBuffer->GetBufferPointer(), vertexShaderBuffer->GetBufferSize(), &m_layout);
    if (FAILED(result))
    {
        MessageBox(hwnd, TEXT("Failed to create the input layout"), TEXT("Error initializaing shader"), MB_OK);
        return false;
    }
```

Here is me actually updating the instance buffer(it is dynamic)

```
result = deviceContext->Map(m_instanceBuffer, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &data);
    if (FAILED(result))
    {
        return false;
    }

    instancesPtr = (InstanceVertex2*)data.pData;

    memcpy(instancesPtr, (void*)instances, sizeof(&m_vertices[0]));

    //now un map

     deviceContext->Unmap(m_instanceBuffer, 0);
```

And finally this is the code where I put the buffers into the device context

```
//set the buffers
    buffers[0] = m_vertexBuffer;
    buffers[1] = m_instanceBuffer;

    //set the strides
    strides[0] = sizeof(InstanceVertex1);
    strides[1] = sizeof(InstanceVertex2);

    //set the offsets
    offsets[0] = 0;
    offsets[1] = 0;
    //set the vertex buffers
    deviceContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 2, buffers, strides, offsets);

    //set the index buffers
    deviceContext->IASetIndexBuffer(m_indexBuffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);

    deviceContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);
```

This does seem like a lot of code to look through but I don't know exactly what is going wrong, I have got instancing and dynamic vertex buffers to work in the past without problems and for some reason I can not get it to work when I combine them.I have nvidea nsight so I can look in the vertex shader and buffers directly, and from what I am looking at I can tell that nothing is getting passed into the instance buffer. I would appreciate any help or pointers anyone is willing to give me so that I can fix my problem.

Comment: Be sure to note that instancing is not supported on ``D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_1`` devices. See [Direct3D feature levels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476876.aspx)

Comment: Its not the feature level, I already got it working.If it was the feature level it would have thrown an error I think and it threw none.Thanks for commenting though.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it turned out the problem lay not in the initialization of the instance buffer but in the way I was updating it, I will include the answer to it so that others might be able to get help with a similar problem.

I changed :

```
result = deviceContext->Map(m_instanceBuffer, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &data);
if (FAILED(result))
{
    return false;
}

instancesPtr = (InstanceVertex2*)data.pData;

memcpy(instancesPtr, (void*)instances, sizeof(&m_vertices[0]));

//now un map

 deviceContext->Unmap(m_instanceBuffer, 0);
```

To :

```
result = deviceContext->Map(m_instanceBuffer, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &data);
    if (FAILED(result))
    {
        return false;
    }

    instancesPtr = (InstanceVertex2*)data.pData;
    for (int i = 0;i < m_vertices.size();i++)
    {
        instancesPtr[i].color = m_vertices[i].color;
        instancesPtr[i].matrixInstance = m_vertices[i].matrixInstance;
        instancesPtr[i].textureID = m_vertices[i].textureID;
        instancesPtr[i].UVAdd = m_vertices[i].UVAdd;
        instancesPtr[i].UVMultiply = m_vertices[i].UVMultiply;
    }

    //memcpy(instancesPtr, (void*)instances, sizeof(&m_vertices[0]));

    //now un map

     deviceContext->Unmap(m_instanceBuffer, 0);
```

I hope this helps someone else with there problem someday, it certainly took me long enough.